# Build extjs for production on container fails

Tags: linux, extjs, containers

we are trying to create a container that we can use to build an extjs application.

Or Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install git -y
RUN apt install openjdk-8-jdk -y
RUN apt install unzip -y
RUN apt install curl -y
COPY cmd-7.4.0.39-linux-64-no_jre.zip .
RUN unzip cmd-7.4.0.39-linux-64-no_jre.zip
RUN chmod +x SenchaCmd-7.4.0.39-linux-amd64.sh
RUN ./SenchaCmd-7.4.0.39-linux-amd64.sh -q -a
RUN rm SenchaCmd-7.4.0.39-linux-amd64.sh
RUN rm cmd-7.4.0.39-linux-64-no_jre.zip
```

After build the image, we create a container, we check out our code and we run:

```
$ /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/sencha app build development
```

This is all good; but when we run:

```
$ /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/sencha app build production
```

If fails with the following error:

```
[ERR] loading page file:///root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.39/ant/build/slicer/theme.html?_baseDir=%2Fdesktop-client%2Fsrc%2Fbuild%2Ftemp%2Fproduction%2FMyAppName%2Fslicer-temp
setting base href to : file:///desktop-client/src/build/temp/production/MyAppName/slicer-temp/
== Unhandled Error ==
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '''Ext.define''')

  file:///desktop-client/src/ext/classic/theme-neptune/overrides/Component.js:1 in global code

[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 2
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMetho
[ERR] dAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 17 seconds
[ERR] /root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.39/plugin.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.39/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml:341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.39/ant/build/app/slice-impl.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.39/ant/build/app/slice-impl.xml:379: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.39/ant/build/app/slice-impl.xml:220: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: phantomjs process exited with code 2
[ERR] A log is available in the file "/desktop-client/src/sencha-error-20220919.log"
```

Comment: Turns out we did not have the ../ext/build folder from extjs checked in as part of the repository. Once we included those files build is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The ..\ext\build files that are part of an app created with the extjs  framework were missing in our repository. Once these files were added, the build worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).